# SpringBoot CommandLineRunner Packages does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing an api project with spring boot. When I want to implement the commandlinerunner in the main class, I get errors. Is my main class not seeing the Model and the Repository? So where am I doing wrong? I am using Java 17, Spring 3.0.4 version. When I delete commandlinerunner on the code, I don't get an error.

```
package com.hsnhut.realestateapi;

import com.hsnhut.realestateapi.model.Seller;
import com.hsnhut.realestateapi.repository.SellerRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.HashSet;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.hsnhut.realestateapi"})
public class RealestateapiApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
private final SellerRepository sellerRepository;

public RealestateapiApplication(SellerRepository sellerRepository) {
    this.sellerRepository = sellerRepository;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RealestateapiApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    sellerRepository.save(new Seller("","Hasan","Hut",new HashSet<>()));
}
}
```

These are my errors:

- java: package com.hsnhut.realestateapi.model does not exist
- java: package com.hsnhut.realestateapi.repository does not exist
- java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SellerRepository
  location: class com.hsnhut.realestateapi.RealestateapiApplication
- java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SellerRepository
  location: class com.hsnhut.realestateapi.RealestateapiApplication

Comment: My models are written with Kotlin Class. When i changed these classes to java class its working.

Comment: if you solved your problem, please close your question